# RestKit - Trying to post object to server

Tags: objective-c, restkit

This has probably been asked a million times, but I'm not getting anywhere from all the examples that I'm finding.

I have the following class:

```
@interface LoginRequest : NSObject
{
    NSString* _deviceId;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* deviceId;

@end
```

And I'm trying to post this to a server, encoded as form key/value in the HTTP body.

I'm using the following to setup the mapping:

```
objectManager.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeFormURLEncoded;

        RKObjectMapping* pmsg = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]];
        [pmsg mapKeyPath: @"deviceId" toAttribute:@"DeviceId"];

        RKObjectMapping* pmsgSerializeMapping = [pmsg inverseMapping];

        [objectManager.mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:pmsgSerializeMapping forClass:[LoginRequest class]];

        [objectManager.router routeClass:[LoginRequest class] toResourcePath:@"/login" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];
```

This was taken from the example here: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Posting-Data-Objects

I'm getting the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<LoginRequest 0x8c9c980> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key DeviceId.'
```

Here's how I'm trying to send my object:

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

LoginRequest* request = [LoginRequest alloc];
request.deviceId = @"Test";

[objectManager postObject:request delegate: self];
```

Can anyone help?

Update: I can confirm that when I don't use the custom key-code mapping stuff, it works. The following I have working:

```
RKObjectMapping* pmsg = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]];
        [pmsg mapAttributes:@"DeviceId", nil];

        [objectManager.mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:pmsg forClass:[LoginRequest class]];

        [objectManager.router routeClass:[LoginRequest class] toResourcePath:@"/login" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your property is named "deviceId", which is lowercase. But you're saying the attribute is "DeviceId" which starts with an uppercase "D".

Comment: But my "mapKeyPath: @"deviceId" toAttribute:@"DeviceId" is specifying that my object key path is "deviceId", and I want to map the json property "DeviceId" to it? So isn't that correct?

Comment: no, the "attribute" is your property in your model object. The "keyPath" is the field name in your JSON.

Comment: No problem. Please don't forget to mark the answer accepted if it helped solve your problem. Thanks!